# MySQL isn't updating tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, database

#### Disclaimer: this is for an assignment. I am not asking that people give me explicit code, only for enough help so that I may see my error, correct it, and prevent similar mistakes in the future.

I'm working on an assignment that asks me to create a table in a database, populate it with a few entries, then create a form and allow users to update the database through the form (this is very basic stuff.) In addition to the updating, users should see their entries after submitting their changes.

One of the requirements is to use an auto-incrementing primary key. As this key has no real importance to the user, I see no need to make it something they'd include in their submission (and so there's no field for it.) Additionally, since it's supposed to auto-increment, giving the option of a manually-added key doesn't really make sense.

So I've put together a small set of fields and MySQL statements, all of which I believe should work. When I have a field to add a key (in this case, `id_no`) and I manually input a value there, the submissions are successfully stored to the database. When I remove that option, however, nothing is submitted to the database.

I should note that my primary key field `id_no` **is** marked for auto-increment, so that's not the problem. Per my understanding and what I've seen by manually inserting entities, auto-incrementing values should be updated automatically without needing to include them in any `insert` statements.

Here's what I've got so far (this is my first MySQL/PHP assignment, so please be gentle):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Actor Database</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").validate();
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>


 <form method="post">
   First Name: <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first" class="required" minlength="3">
   <br>
   Last Name: <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last" class="required" minlength="3">
   <br>
   <!--ID Number: <input name="id_no" type="text" id="id_num" class="required digits" maxlength="5">
   <br>-->
   Photo: <input name="photo" type="file" id="photo" class="required">
   <br>
   <input type="submit" id="submit">
 </form>

 <?php

 $dbhost = '*******************';
 $dbname = '*******************';
 $dbuser = '*******************';
 $dbpass = '*******************';

 $mysql_handle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
 or die("Error connecting to database server");

 mysql_select_db($dbname, $mysql_handle)
 or die("Error selecting database: $dbname");

 //mysql_query("INSERT INTO Actors(first_name, last_name) VALUES('Anne', 'Hathaway')");

 $id_no = array_key_exists("id_no", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["id_no"] : 0;
 $first_name = array_key_exists("first_name", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["first_name"] : '';
 $last_name = array_key_exists("last_name", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["last_name"] : '';
 $photo = array_key_exists("photo", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["photo"] : NULL;

 if ($id_no <= 0) {
  echo "";
 } else if ($id_no > 0) {
  $rs = mysql_query("SELECT id_no FROM Actors WHERE id_no = ".$id_no);
  if (mysql_numrows($rs) == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Actors(id_no, last_name, first_name) VALUES("
        . $id_no
        . ",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($last_name) . "'"
        . ",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($first_name) . "')"
      );
  } else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE Actors 
      SET last_name  = '".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name). "',
      SET first_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."'
      WHERE id_no ".$id_no
      );
  }
  }

  $results = mysql_query('SELECT id_no, last_name, first_name, photo FROM Actors');
  $nrows = mysql_numrows($results);

  echo "<table>";
  for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($results, $i, "first_name")). " " .htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($results, $i, "last_name"))."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";


 mysql_close($mysql_handle);

 ?>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but too big for a comment.

here's some general tips to impress your prof with:

1) array_key_exists is somewhat redundant, and you can make your checks a bit more readable with:

```
$photo = isset($_REQUEST['photo']) ?: NULL;
```

(note that this shortcut syntax only works in php 5.3+)

2) You have no error handling on your query calls, which means you're simply assuming they always succeed. Database operations have exactly **ONE** way to succeed ("Don't fail"), and nearly infinite ways of failing. Always check return values for failure:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

should be on every single db operation  as a bare minimum.

3) kudos for being aware of sql injection problems and at least using mysql_real_escape_string() to mitigate them

4) boos for still using the mysql functions. Switching to the PDO or mysqli library and using prepared statements and placeholders will definitely make this project look better to the prof.

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat your `where id_no` is missing an ='s

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Actors 
  SET last_name  = '".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name). "',
  first_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."'
  WHERE id_no =".$id_no
  );
```

Comment: update should also only have a single `set`. `update table set field=value, field=value, etc...`

Answer (score 1):

When you insert you do not need to include the id_no if there is a default value which is the case when auto_increment is set. So remove id_no from the insert statement.

The logic with id_no needs to be changed. Either have a new command/action that sets id_no to 0 which indicates that this is a new record; or determine and set a real primary key by way of a unique index and search for that to determine if a record already exists.

Good luck and thanks for the disclaimer :-)